# IN Clause causes Execution plan to change from Nested Loops to Hash Match

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, view, cte

I'm tuning a query and have discovered some behaviour I'm not clear about.

If I remove the `WHERE IN` clause the query runs in 3 seconds instead of 3 minutes.

There only 7 rows returned in the result since there are only 7 items in the `IN` clause.

Thinking this was a bit odd, I started trying to get both parts of the query behaving individually, however no matter what I've tried the `IN` clause causes the long execution time.

Looking at the execution plan I can see that it's taking some joins and converting them from `Nested Loops` to `Hash Match`.

I've diced up the SQL so the single `SELECT` is now split between a `View`, `CTE` and `SELECT`.  I would have expected the `IN` clause to not impact what is happening inside of the `View`, but it is.

The execution plans are: [with the `IN` clause](http://www.nosilleg.com/stackexchange/dba/24896/wJeERWJ9Ar/dba-24896-executionplan.sqlplan) and [without the `IN` clause](http://www.nosilleg.com/stackexchange/dba/24896/wJeERWJ9Ar/dba-24896-executionplan-sans-in.sqlplan).  Please be gentle regarding the quality of the query; it's a work in progress on an inherited project and I'm by no means a proper DBA.

Selecting all 1.8 million rows from the `View` takes ~1 minute; executing the `CTE` by itself takes ~3 seconds; executing the full query takes ~3 minutes.

How can I convince SQL Server to maintain the `Nested Loops` join instead of switching to `Hash Match` when I add in the `IN` clause?  Or is there something else that I should be trying?

Comment: Can you post the actual (not estimated) execution plan somewhere? Trying to reverse engineer a query plan from a word problem is not very fun.

Comment: What is `AnIDColumn`? This doesn't exist as a column in your CTE so the query you posted would be invalid. Please give your actual query. Also definition of `[AView]` would be good.

Comment: Agreed with Martin. Post what you have, not some dumb-downed version. We're smart people and we can read code. We can't read the things you've edited out for brevity.

Comment: Actual execution plan is now provided.

Comment: Thanks for posting the plan. Still having a look at it but I count 22 joins in there and see that `StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="TimeOut"`. There is also a cardinality error that seems to get worse throughout the plan so at some points it is doing nested loops joins with estimated one execution but actual over 3 million.

Comment: Could you also supply the entire query text? It is truncated in the plan. I would probably divide this query up into several smaller ones using a temporary table to materialize the intermediate results though.

Comment: @MartinSmith I reformatted the query and have uploaded the new execution plan with the full query now included. Removing the `IN` clause makes the query complete in 3 seconds, so I presume the `StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="TimeOut"` doesn't happen in that case.

Comment: It might still show that. It just means SQL Server didn't have enough time to exhaustively consider all the (many) permutations for your 20 table join. Any chance you could also upload the fast plan for us to look at? I see the hash joins but the big cardinality errors don't seem to affect the build side which is where I would have thought they would be much more of a problem. Wondering if there is some other difference.

Comment: @MartinSmith I've updated the question with the additional query plan. And you were right, the `TimeOut` is still present.

Comment: @nosilleg - That's interesting. The big cardinality errors don't appear at all in that plan. The join **order** is different and it is not processing anywhere near the same number of rows (BTW I am pasting this XML into SQL Sentry Plan Explorer and they show up glaringly obviously as big thick lines)

Comment: BTW Am I missing something but why are you doing some of the joins twice? `cjl,cjl_d` `pcjl,pcjl_d` `s360qjl,s360qjl_d`. The `_d` suffixed ones look to have identical predicates to the ones without the suffix.

Comment: @MartinSmith the "joins twice" thing is text translations, once for the users desired language and again for the default language. In the case of this query they both happen to be the same. I've removed those columns and joins previously with no noticeable impact.

Comment: @nosilleg - That's a shame because short of forcing the whole plan shape with join hints or a plan guide simplifying the query would seem the easiest way of getting a good plan. You might try looking into the joins where the actual vs estimated number of rows are orders of magnitudes out and see if you can do anything about that (e.g. are you missing any multi column statistics that may be useful)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can force nested loops by using OPTION(LOOP JOIN) however, I would advise using OPTION(LOOP JOIN, MERGE JOIN) this is working with the optimiser rather than against it and is saying do what you want as long as its not a hash match.

But I would also dig a little deeper. With the IN clause it is possible that SQL is performing multiple index scans as opposed to a single table scan, so you may need to use an WITH(INDEX(0)) instead.

If you add SET STATISTICS IO at the top of the batch and run it with and then without the IN clause and check the number of physical and logical reads for each, as well as the read-ahead reads, this will prove or disprove my theory.

Comment: @SQLKiwi FYI, I've added the execution plans now.

Comment: @PeteCarter Adding the `OPTION` increased the non-`IN` from 3 to 7 seconds, and the `IN` query was closer to 4 minutes.  `STATISTICS IO` is reporting 10s of thousands of logical reads without `IN` and millions with `IN`. Putting the `WITH(INDEX(0))` on the `VIEW` doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2):

Put an index on: `(HasAnswered, AnIDColumn)` from the appropriate underlying table and INCLUDE any other columns you reference.

Presumably you meant to group by AnIDColumn inside your CTE. So without better indexing options, it's likely to calculate all the aggregates first and then filter them. You want to persuade the filter on AnIDColumn to happen first, and that's best done by adding your ideal index.

You're asking about joins, when your query doesn't show any - the comments are right that your question is incomplete.

Comment: I have now supplied the execution plans with the question. Sorry about the poor initial pseudo query.